# Dependency injection of events

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

Could somebody describe how should looks like class Worker with two events which triggers after some action is happened.
I have class Worker with one method ExecuteAsync. Inside this method I'm executing method i.e. DoStuff(). After that I want execute events. Event one and event two has different logic and have independent arguments which should be passed.
What goals I want to achieve.

1. I want to mock those events and test Worker without side effects.
2. Class Worker and events is SRP classes.
3. I can easily inject another realization of events without breaking my code.

I'm not completely understand this thing:

1. How should look's like realisation with injecting "body" of events.
2. Could I execute one event but inject inside it file search logic and sending http logic?

```
public class Worker
{
    public event EventHandler<FileFoundArgs> FileFound;
    public event EventHandler<SendHttpArgs> SendHttp;
    
    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        DoStuff();
        FileFound?.Invoke(this, new FileFoundArgs(file));
        SendHttp?.Invoke(this, new SendHttpArgs(file));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, what stops you setting `FileFound` and `SendHttp` to a mock implementation in your test harness?

Comment: Triggering an event will have no effect as long as nobody does subscribe to this event. With `worker.FileFound += Worker_FileFound` you can attach an event handler of your choice in your test code.